# Why does fluorine form only one hydrogen bond, but oxygen forms two?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, hydrogen-bond

Oxygen forms *two* hydrogen bonds as it has *two* lone pairs. So, why does fluorine only forms *one* hydrogen bond having *three* lone pairs?

Both oxygen and fluorine have nearly the same size, so steric hindrance should not be an issue.

I'm aware of the following facts, so please do not use them as an explanation:

- hydrogen forms only one hydrogen bond;
- fluorine forms one hydrogen bond in hydrogen fluoride $\ce{HF}$;
- oxygen forms two hydrogen bonds in water $\ce{H2O}.$

Are there any compounds in which fluorine forms *three* hydrogen bonds?

Comment: The number of lone pairs has no importance in the calculation of the bonds of an atom. Only the number of electrons non included in lone pairs is important. Oxygen has $2$ such electrons. It can make $2$ bonds with $\ce{H}$ atoms. Fluor has only one such electron. So it can make only one bond with $\ce{H}$  atoms.

Comment: Be aware of possible confusion of "fluorine H-bond" as 1/ an ordinary polar covalent bond H-F as in hydrogen fluoride. 2/ Hydrogen bond as e.g. between $\ce{HF}$ molecules as $\ce{H-F\bond{...}H-F}$.

Comment: Who said F only forms one H-bond, and in which contetxt?

Answer (score 6):

Fluorine in hydrogen fluoride can form only a limited amount of hydrogen bonds because there is only one (protic) hydrogen atom per fluorine. [Ammonium fluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_fluoride) has enough protic hydrogens to form hydrogen bonds with all four electron pairs on each fluorine — and so they do, in a wurtzite-type arrangement of the ions.